# How can I use two different CSS frameworks in React.js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using two CSS frameworks in index.html, as follow
Materialize.css for Login/Sign In, and slick.css for rest of my website.
When frameworks are defined as:

**Materialize.css:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```

**Slick.css**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
```

Then Output:

[Home page Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SuUl.png)

[Login Page Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFSvC.png)

If frameworks are defined as:

**Slick.css**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
```

**Materialize.css:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Then Output:

[Home page Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHrI0.png)

[Login page Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fepMn.png)

But it implement last declare CSS framework on whole website.
how can I implement different CSS frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Usage of global style CSS/Javascript frameworks in modern frontend frameworks like React, Angular and Vue is possible, but highly discouraged.

> **If you want to, you can do it and there is nothing special you need to do for them to work.**

Let's say you include Bootstrap in your web page and you want to use the button styles:

```js
const SomeComponent = _props => (
  <button className='btn btn-primary'>Hey I'm a button</button>
)
```

That's it. Now then, what happens if two global CSS use the same class? Like '.btn' for instance. In this case the last one to be included will win, and there's [pretty much] nothing you can do to solve the dilemma. This is the problem with global CSS and the reason modern projects avoid it at all costs.

A solution for this collision problem would be to use CSS-in-JS solution, in which we import CSS into a Javascript file and only use the CSS selectors and classes we need. This may work to some degree, but it still would ne a hack with associated limitations.

In practice, we only force the integration of vanilla JS libraries [with React] if they are very low level and there is no [good] adapter library for the specific frontend framework you are using (React, Angular).

---

This is where opinion-based part of the answer starts.

For Material design and React, it would make much more sense to use an implementation of Material design in React components, like [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), which is much more easier to integrate with React than vanilla JS and CSS implementation of Material design like Materialize.

The same approach is similar for Slick. Google 'react carousel' and you'll get at least 2 good implementations of a carousel UI that you can easily integrate into a React project.